# Generating random integer between two inputs Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, math

I'm trying to write a function (`GetPositiveInteger`) that generates a random integer between variables `a` and `b`.  if `a > b`, it's supposed to switch the values of the two so that `b=>a` before generating the Number.

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding the question or what because I can't figure out where I'm meant to be converting `a` and `b` to integers and my program keeps just returning `NaN`. here's my code maybe someone could take a look at it?

```js
function GetRandomInteger(a, b, c) {
  a = Number(a), b = Number(b);
  if (a > b) {
    var a = 2,
      b = 1,
      c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c;
  } else {
    var x = parseInt(Math.random() * b) + a;
  }

  return x;
}

let x;
console.log(Number(GetRandomInteger(x)));
```

Comment: Why are you setting `a = 2` and `b = 1`?

Comment: What is the `c` parameter for?

Comment: The function takes 3 arguments, you're calling it with only 1. You also never set `x` before calling the function.

Comment: So I could switch the value of a and b if a was higher than b I thought that was what we're supposed to do? This question is so convoluted lol I hate that I'm struggling so much with it

Comment: Should x be set in the parameters part ? Ugg I feel so dumb I've legit been at this for 3 hours. We haven't covered it in class at all so it's taking me a hot min

Comment: Is it just me or did SO remove the "no homework exercises" rule? Because it's no longer in the list of reasons to flag or close?

Comment: Also, this function works fine when you actually pass it values for `a` and `b`. Currently when you're running the function, you're trying to get a random number between `undefined` and `undefined`, no wonder it says NotANumber

Comment: Oh shoot I didn't even know that was a rule ! I can delete my question I don't want to get in trouble

Answer (score 2):

When `a > b`, you're setting them to specific numbers before swapping them, instead of swapping the original values.

The code that generates the random number shouldn't be in `else`, because you won't run that after swapping `a` and `b`. It should just be after the `if`.

You don't need the `c` parameter. Use a temporary variable declared inside the function when swapping.

Use `Math.floor()` to convert a floating point number to an integer. `parseInt()` is for parsing strings (it will work in this case because it first converts the float to a string, but it's better to use the more specific function).

You need to call the function with two arguments. In the example below I just hard-coded them, but you can use your function that asks the user for numbers. Just use it twice to set two variables.

```js
function GetRandomInteger(a, b) {
  a = Number(a), b = Number(b);
  if (a > b) {
    let temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  }
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * b) + a;

  return x;
}

console.log(GetRandomInteger(1, 10));
console.log(GetRandomInteger(15, 3));
```